# Git prompts for username and password for git push origin master command

Tags: git, github

[image]

Every time I was trying to push the new commits to the master branch through git push origin master command, git was prompting me with credentials. I wanted to convert the url from HTTPS to SSH through these commands:

```
$git remote add origin https://github.com/Ananya2001-an/FirstRepository
$git config --global credential.helper store
$git config --global credential.helper cache
```

But now though it is not asking for the credentials, it's still not pushing the commits and instead showing me that Permission to access is denied and I can't read from my remote repository.
Kindly help me with this issue that I am facing right now.

Comment: If you want to use your ssh key (and you should) then your git remote should be `git@github.com:Ananya2001-an/FirstRepository.git`  You should update your question with what you get from `git remote -v`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get git repository link from your GitHub account

e.g. https://github.com/imrankabir/my-react-app.git

git remote set-url origin https://imrankabir@github.com/imrankabir/my-react-app.git

Notice the username added after https://{imrankabir@}

now run the following command

git config credential.helper store

git pull origin master

it will ask for your GitHub password just for once same it on the machine.

if the future it will not ask for the password again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did try it, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to convert the url from HTTPS to SSH  ...

OK:

> ... through these commands:
>
> ```
> $ git remote add origin https://github.com/Ananya2001-an/FirstRepository
> $ git config --global credential.helper store
> $ git config --global credential.helper cache
> ```

That won't work at all.  The URL for the remote `origin` is the *last* argument to `git remote add origin` or `git remote set-url origin`,  and for it to be an *ssh* remote, it must *begin with `ssh://`* rather than `https://`.<sup>1</sup>

The `credential.helper` setting exists specifically for `https://` URLs.  The `git config --global` command you're using will remove the old global setting and replace it with a new global setting, so the effect of the *first* such command is completely wiped away by the *second* one.

Wherever you got these commands, then, has done you a big disservice: they gave you three wrong commands instead of one right one.  On the other hand, if you meant to change the URL from ssh to https—the exact opposite of what you said—they gave you ... well, three wrong commands, still.

Your image (side note: use text, not images; see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) shows that you *already have an ssh URL*.  We can tell because this:

> ```
> git remote add origin https://github.com/Ananya2001-an/FirstRepository
> ```

gives you an error:

> ```
> error: remote origin already exists.
> ```

Meanwhile, your `git push` says:

> ```
> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
> ```

and this error occurs only for ssh URLs.

If you wish to *change* the URL of the *existing* remote `origin`, use:

```
git remote set-url origin ...
```

(filling in the `...` part with the desired URL).

To get your existing ssh URL to work, you should:

1. verify that you have the *correct* URL; and
2. debug your ssh connection to GitHub using `ssh -Tv git@github.com`.

You can do these steps in either order.

The `credential.helper` setting (`store` or `cache`) is used only for the `https://` URLs; you can leave this set to `cache` if you like, regardless of what you do for the URL.  However, on Windows systems, you might want to use the third-party [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) ("GCM").  (I don't use Windows myself and have never used GCM; I use ssh.)

---

Technically, there are other ways to spell ssh remote URLs for Git, but "what the URL starts with" is a good start.  URLs in general take the form `https://host.name/path/to/resource` or `ftp://host.name/path/to/resource` or `mailto:user@host.name` or `ssh://host.name/path/to/resource`.  Note the pattern here: we start with the *type*, like `https` or `ftp` or `ssh` or `mailto`, then we have a colon `:`, then we have `//host.name` for most cases.  Sometimes we have `user@host.name`, and you might use this with `ssh://` URLs.